# $\mathbb{G_a}$ is being linear algebraic group, but first diagram does not commute?

Tags: algebraic-groups

**Question:** Why they are all assume it trivial, but I cannot make it commute the diagram in the first axiom of being, linear algebraic group (for $A=k[s]$).

*Definition 3.48.(ref.Mukai An Introduction to Invariants and Moduli (Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics)*
Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Then $G=\mathrm{Spm} A$ is called an affine algebraic group if there exist $k$-algebra homomorphisms
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mu: A \rightarrow A \otimes_k A \text { (coproduct) } \\
& \epsilon: A \rightarrow k \quad \text { (coidentity) } \\
& \iota: A \rightarrow A \quad \text { (coinverse) } \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
satisfying the following three conditions.
(i) The following diagram commutes:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>{\mu}>> A \otimes_k A\\
@V\mu VV  @VV1_A\otimes\mu V\\
A \otimes_k A @>{\mu\otimes 1_A}>> A \otimes_k A \otimes_k A
\end{CD}

we have also second and third axioms to be satisfied (I have checked there are no problem)

**Problem**
Example 3.50. The spectrum of a polynomial ring in one variable $A=k[s]$ can be given the structure of an affine algebraic group by defining $\mu(s)=$ $s \otimes 1+1 \otimes s, \epsilon(s)=0$ and $\iota(s)=-s$. This group is denoted by $\mathbb{G}_{\mathrm{a}}$. As a functor, it assigns to a $k$-algebra $R$ the additive group $R$ itself. As a variety, of course, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$.

**The attempt** Since our $k-$ Algebra is a polynomial ring $k[s]$ let us try with only $s\in A=k[s]$

$s$ is sent to $s \otimes 1+1 \otimes s$ then, by $1\otimes\mu $, sent to $s\otimes 1 \otimes 1+ s\otimes1\otimes1+ 1\otimes s \otimes 1 +1\otimes 1\otimes s$

in other way

$s$ is sent to $s \otimes 1+1 \otimes s$ then, by $\mu \otimes1 $, sent to $s\otimes 1 \otimes 1+ 1\otimes s \otimes1+ 1\otimes 1 \otimes s +1\otimes 1\otimes s$

So in this calculations $3$ terms in each sides are cancelled but $s\otimes 1\otimes 1$ and $1\otimes 1\otimes s$  clearly since $s$ is not in the field $k$ we cannot take it to in front of the equation.

So what am I missing, can you point it out?

Comment: Hint: what is $\mu(1)$? What should be $(1 \otimes\mu)(s\otimes 1)$?

Comment: aaooo, I thought instead of s I couldhave put $1$ but since they are all k-alg morphism, $\mu(1)=1\otimes 1$ instead of $1\otimes 1 + 1\otimes 1$ right? omg

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4623824/104041)